Разделить список директории на дочерние и родительские
Подскажите правильное направление или пример.
Есть список:
$list = ['folder', 'folder2','folder2/items','folder2/items/css','folder2/images'];

Нужно получить многомерный массив с дочерними элементами:
$list = [
   ["name" => "folder", "path" => "/folder", children: []],
   ["name" => "folder2", "path" => "/folder2", children: 
      [
        "name" => "items", "path" => "/folder2/items", children: 
           [
               "name" => "css", "path" => "folder2/items/css", children: []
           ],
        "name" => "images", "path" => "/folder2/images", children: [],
      ]
   ],
];


Правильное направление - не делать никогда список в таком виде. А делать его в более правильном виде.

Я получаю его с удалённого сервера в таком виде. Думаю лучше сделать данную задачу рекурсией.

Надо написать разработчиком сей ужасной поделки и высказать всё, что об этом думают в сообществе разработчиков)) Ну  и заставить переделывать

А делать да...рекурсией можно
